# how to reverse a sequence

Tags: sql, sequence, sequences

my table

```
EMP_NO                 EMP_NAME   
---------------------- ---------- 
1                      ram        
2                      mohan      
3                      raju       
4                      santosh    
5                      nikil      
6                      praveen    
7                      manju      
8                      hari       
9                      kumar      
10                     hareesh    
11                     chndra
```

i created sequence on the emp_no(that sequence name is sequence_1).now i want query for sequence is started with max value`(11)` in above and decrease the sequence upto `(1)`

my expected result is

```
EMP_NO                 EMP_NAME   
---------------------- ---------- 
11                      ram        
10                     mohan      
9                     raju       
8                      santosh    
7                      nikil      
6                      praveen    
5                      manju      
4                      hari       
3                      kumar      
2                     hareesh    
1                     chndra
```

for this purpose give me query please.thanks in advance

Comment: "Here's my data, write my queries for me! Oh and make me sandwich plzthanx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Sql Sever

```
Select Row_Number() Over(Order By [EMP_NO] Desc) as Emp_No,
       EMP_NAME  
       from TableName
       Order By [Emp_No] Desc
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d54c/1)

For Oracle Sql Developer

```
Select Row_Number() Over(Order By "EMP_NO" Desc) as "Emp_No",
       "EMP_NAME"  
       from Table1
       Order By "Emp_No" Desc
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31f00/1)

Comment: The question is tagged with `SQL` which refers to standard SQL **not** to SQL Server. Please avoid using non-standard identifier quotes in that case. (the `[..]` are invalid in standard SQL).

Comment: ur query showing error is    SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @user2775287 what is your rdbms...sql server , mysql ,oracle or any'other

Comment: showing error    Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: can you tell me what is your RDBMS?

Comment: @user2775287 try above mention answer

Comment: thanq i got a require result

Comment: y you keep that in quotes?

Comment: @user2775287 in oracle columnname are standarly given in qoutes that is gud practice

Comment: can you explain above query how to execute pls

Comment: its very simple row number geneate serial no for your table in order of emp no since it desc so it will mark 11 as 1 and so on....

Comment: thanq for explaining..thanq lot

Comment: using sequence it is not working ?

Comment: using sequence my expecting out put doesn't come?

Comment: @user2775287 that is the way to do it ...

Comment: how to do that can explain pls

Comment: i can not understand your real oroblem...if u have table like aobve than it should work...

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from emp order by emp_no desc;
```

Comment: it would not give desire results see and check again

Comment: You misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ Thilo u r answer is right but in your query names also changed my expecting result is no need to change names ,only changing emp_no..

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select max(emp_no) from emp)-emp_no+1,emp_name from emp
```

Comment: ur query showing error

Comment: ur query showing error